# Selenium check that text is not present

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to check that text is now not present on a webpage without my test failing

I have achieved this by catching the exception but is there a better way of doing this?

```
try {
    selenium.isTextPresent(selenium.getText("27"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Element does not exhist");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with try-catch.

Anyway, what you have should be more of a `isElementPresent("27")` since you discard the return value of `isTextPresent()`. Moreover, if the element exists, then `isTextPresent()` will always return true, because ... well, you took the text out of existing element, it *has* to be there. In this case, it is enough just to assure whether the element exists or not.

But if you do actually need it in real code somehow, then what about `if (selenium.isElementPresent("27") && selenium.isTextPresent(selenium.getText("27")))` ?

Also, `getXpathCount(//*[@id='27' and text()]) == 0` expression does the trick, too. It count the number of returned elements that have id=27 and contain some text. If that's a zero, there are none.

Comment: Thank you this gave me a better understanding of the isElement vs isText. I am quite new to Selenium! (on a side note, not that it matters he is actually a she :P)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `assertTextNotPresent` OR `verifyTextNotPresent`

@  Slanec Yes, its my mistake
You can use

```
verifyFalse(selenium.isTextPresent("text"));
assertFalse(selenium.isTextPresent("text"));
```

Comment: Only in Selenium-IDE, I think?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#isTextPresent%28java.lang.String%29) you should be able to say the following:

```
selenium.isTextPresent("27"));
```

This returns a boolean so if you want to make sure it is not there... check it is false.

Comment: Actually, no. His code takes the text from element with id=27.

Comment: @Slanec: Perhaps the code should be more as follow:
`!selenium.isTextPresent(expectedValue) || !selenium.getText(locator).equals(expectedValue)`
where `expectedValue` is the actual text he's looking for and locator is the element to find it in?

Comment: Exactly right. The code doesn't really make much sense since it is effectively only a `isElementPresent("27")` test.